# How to move projects from a server to local hard disk or removable drive?

Tags: qgis, qgs

I have a QGIS project on a desktop that I need to move to a laptop to take into the field.

Whilst in the office, both PCs talk to the project on server via a persistent mapped drive (L:) - ie. project lives in L:\My Project\QGIS.

When I go to the field, I mirror the project onto a USB 3.0 thumb drive but in order to access it I need to remap the L drive on the laptop to point at the thumb drive rather than the network server.

This is relatively straightforward but does involve having to remap the L drive back to the network when I arrive back.

I would prefer to tell QGIS that whilst in the field my project is another drive (eg. M) so I can leave the L mapping alone.

In my case all my files live in the same project area so project reparenting would be relatively simple from a coding standpoint. But having said that from QGIS's standpoint, there is no necessity for all files to live on the same drive and thus reparenting would be more complex.

Thinking about what I have just written, perhaps the good old DOS SUBST command is the easiest option for doing what I want to do.

Comment: I use QGIS with relative paths on all PCs (though different drive letters), and keep the folder structure identical. That way I only need to open the .qgs file, and all layers can get opened. Any obstacles against that on your side?

Comment: Perhaps with the QConsolidate plugin (experimental) ?